# Sequrity in Authentication a user

Tags: express, authentication, express-session

I write toy-server on Node and i want to create system authentication a user. For that purpose i install express and express-session.
This setting exprerss-session

```
app.use(session({
key: 'user_sid',
secret: 'somerandomstuffs',
resave: false,
saveUnitialized: false,
cookie: {
expires: 600000 }
```

While new user signup or a user login, i regenerate session with the function - res.session.regenerate() and create new the req propertie

```
req.session.user = User.dataValues
```

The problem is  begin if the user want to edit his account.  I think do this

```
if(req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) 
    { user can change his account }
else { res.redirect('/login') }
```

But i'm afraid this is not enough. I want not install another program, i want make this as simple as i could.